# Kernel compilation for Click modular router

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, router

I am trying to install Click modular router in kernel mode. For this I need to patch and compile a custom kernel. I am presently running ubuntu on kernel 2.6.22.14 and I am trying to compile the kernel 2.6.24 from kernel.org

I patched the downloaded kernel with the I use the /boot/config file of my present kernel to do a compilation of new kernel via make oldconfig. I then did a make modules_install and finally make install.

The kernel compiled fine and boots nicely. However when I try to insert the kernel module Click.o it fails.

I am guessing I need to do some changes in config file before installing. Please help.

Comment: I guess it failed because of missing symbols. See what these symbols are, and it may help you understand the problem.

Comment: Yeah it says unknown symbol in click.o 
I searched on the official forum of click they said something about floating point support in kernel. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: You really should try to provide information in your question, rather than hints in the comments. If your error message is `unresolved symbol __divdi3`, why not say so?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better way is to try patchless installation of Click in kernel mode. Patchless installation works on modern kernel versions. For example you can use Debian 6.0 Squeeze (kernel 2.6.32) or Debian Wheezy (kernel 3.2). I checked, it works.

When you get error like that on Wheezy:

```
=========================================
Can't find include/linux/skbuff.h in /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build.
Are you sure /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build contains Linux kernel source?
=========================================
```

You might need to apply that hack: https://github.com/kohler/click/issues/104